# Laravel Eloquent / fluent

Tags: laravel

When fetching all rows from an Eloquent Model :

```
$pin = Pin::all();
```

I get an array that looks like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(Pin)#36 (5) {
    ["attributes"]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["creator"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    ["original"]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["creator"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["relationships"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["exists"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["includes"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

As when I use Fluent instead:

```
$pin = DB::table('pins')->get();
```

I get as a plain array without the **"Attribute", "Orginial", "realtionships"** .. indexes.

How can I use Eloquent so that it returns a Plain Array like FLuent does?

Comment: You cannot. The whole point of Eloquent is to have a bunch of objects returned that you can act upon with certain methods that are domain-specific for these models.

Comment: I see, so in that case are you aware of a quick way to get the data out of this array so i can encode it json (Trying to send that to Backbone collection)? Thanks

Comment: @silkAdmin please see the modified answer below. Use The Eloquent Response to give a nice JSON payload to work with frameworks like Backbone, Angularjs etc.

Comment: You can use Pin::all ()-> toArray ()

Comment: As @iavery said, use `->toArray()` since Laravel 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its very simple.

```
$pins = Pin::get();
foreach($pins as $p){
 $pin[] = $p->to_array();
}
```

or if you want to send out JSON object, try using

```
$pins = Pin::all();
return Response::eloquent($pins);
```

or if you have an Array to be converted to json output than use

```
return Response::json(array('name' => 'Batman'));
```

Comment: @silkAdmim As Franz have pointed in his comment, the resources will be there. You can do a foreach loop and get an array using to_array() method

Comment: @silkAdmin you are welcome, and enjoy using Laravel. :) cheers

Comment: Also check out the `eloquent_to_json()` helper function.

Answer (score 3):

With Laravel 4 you can just do:

```
//get all pins from db
public function index(){
  return Pin::all();
}

//get specific pin from db
public function show($id){
  return Pin::find($id);
}
```

that will return your data in Json format

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a built in `to_array()` function so you could do something like this.

```
$pins = Pin::all();
foreach($pins as $pin) {
    $pin_array = $pin->to_array();
    /* Do something with pin array here */
}
```

Hope that helps :D

Comment: Thanks though to_array method is not available as an array is return ed from all() and get() and not an object.

Comment: @silkAdmin Yes but it is an Array of Models(Objects) and you need to do a foreach loop through the array to fetch each object and than call the to_array() method on the single object.

Answer (score 0):

OR

```
$model->original;
// but still do a foreach loop.
// Like so

$pins = Pin::all();
foreach($pins as $pin) {
    $pin_array = $pin->original;
    /* Do something with pin array here */
}
```